# Unity 2019.1.0f2: Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I didn't touch anything but:

- launch Unity Hub
- clicked on "Official Releases"
- choose Unity 2019.1.0f2
- installed it
- opened my projects

When the (very long) import is done, I get this error :

```
Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file.
You need to use Blender 2.45-2.49 or 2.58 and later versions for direct Blender import to work.
```

Of course, I'm using the latest version of Blender (`2.79b`) and everything was working flawlessly with Unity `2018.3.13f`.

So none of my projects work because of this problem. If I re-open it in previous Unity version (`2018.3.13f`) ***it works***.

Everything I've found so far on Internet is about "Microsoft released something that made Python work differently hence this problem". But this can't be that problem right now.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lates version of Blender is the [`2.80 Beta`](https://www.blender.org/2-8/)

According to [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1622769/blender-could-not-convert-the-blend-file-to-fbx-fi-1.html) it seems to be a Unity "bug".

Apparently they had to change something in the import script in order to work with `Blender 2.80` which at the same moment broke the import for files created with older Blender versions.

`Unity 2018.3` had the [issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/blender-2-dot-8-files-not-compatible-with-unity) the other way round and could not open files created with `Blender 2.80`.

---

The workaround from that post was to copy the

```
2018.3.XXX\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity-BlenderToFBX.py
```

from a Unity 2018.3 install into the the new 2019.1.0f2 installation and overwrite the according file

```
2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity-BlenderToFBX.py
```

---

Alternatively you can always manually [export the Blender file (the best example I've found)](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/guides/3d/3d-software/blender-3d-object-export/)(there are tons of tutorials but apparently none from Blender itself ^^) to FBX than there should be no(less) problems importing it into Unity.

Comment: Unity "bug"? How strange, they test their releases with so many deep and internal tests! **`:)`**

Comment: I know right ^^ actually I looked into the script and didn't see why it shouldn't work .. it basically just added a new `if` case for blender version 2.8 so ...

Comment: I did tried this last night but my Unity 2019.1.0f2 still cannot recognize .blend file. Do I need to reimport?

Comment: Update: now everything works. So many deep and internal tests....

Comment: FYI I've made a small game on Unity, tried Godot and switched forever on Godot. It's much better suited for indie developpers

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had this problem with unity 2020.1.16f1 and blender 2.91 on windows.  Posting my fix here in case it helps others.

give the Unity hub and the installed unity.exe  "run as administrator" privilege's so that the intermediate files have the permision to be written.   Also, verify that blender 2.91 is set as the system default for  "open with" on all .blend files.

Comment: Thanks! I broke my script (Unity-BlenderToFBX.py) and reverted it, but it still wouldn't work. I had just upgraded to Blender 3.0 and set it to by the default blender installation (there is a button in the blender preferences). Once I right-clicked a .blend file and chose Blender 2.93 again, Unity Blender importer works again! (In Unity, rightclick -> Reimport)

Answer (score 2):

Blender 3.0 is the issue for those that have the problem again! Download the LTS 2.93 Version and make sure that .blend files are now opened with this one, that fixes it!