# Problem with files blend in Unity-2019.1.0f2

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Unity-2019.1.0f2 doesn't recognize the .blend format, 
this is how it looks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M9JB.png)

The only files that I have tried and work for me are (.fbx and .obj)

The .blend files only works for me in  Unity-2018.2.7f1

Comment: Which version of Blender do you have installed on your machine?

Comment: I proved with blender 2.79 and now I have the 2.80 with the same results

Comment: Honestly this sounds more like a bug you should be reporting to Unity Technologies than a question for SO

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752495/unity-2019-1-0f2-blender-could-not-convert-the-blend-file-to-fbx-file/55752691#55752691